# Where does build.gradle fetch the "compile" dependencies

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

For example if you add this for your dependencies:

> compile 'com.birbit:android-priority-jobqueue:2.0.1'

What is the url to which android studio goes and fetches the library? I have limited network access and I need that link to give to the network admin, so that he allows me to permanently link android studio to that link.

Answer (score 0):

By default Gradle in Android Studio is configured to use Maven Central repository. Unfortunately, it does have multiple mirrors. I'd suggest adding

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
}
```

to your build.gradle to make sure it will always use link provided.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Does this mean that when I see: ` repositories {
        jcenter()
    }`   it goes to fetch at the link you've just shared

Answer (score 0):

jcenter() means https://jcenter.bintray.com/. If you use this inside your repositories gradle will try fetch your artifacts from here.

If you define more repository under repositories{} block it will search your artifacts on it too.